# XML to XSLT transformation

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Dear friends,
                We are developing healthcare app which will monitory patient data from remote and display the patient EcG in dynamic graphs is my requirement , basically I am new to XML and XSLT.  so what I wanted to know how to transfer the xml EcG data into xslt so that then in linux xsltproc command can transfer xsl file into html file  and I can view in browser.

Basic example I know but graphics like lines chat I am confusing how to do ?
please if any one knows let me know thanks in advance. any reference or any links or any example is also ok and great if any one shares.

Comment: You should better improved your question a little, such adding an example of a file basename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't transfer your XML data to XSLT. With XSLT you can define a stylesheet which defines how to transform XML data (to HTML in your case). So you apply XSLT stylesheet *to* your XML data.

When you have your XSLT defined, you can use xsltproc like this:

```
xsltproc stylesheet.xsl myData.xml
```

You can start with this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/) to get some idea how it works. (Click "Try it yourself" to see an example of an XML document, XSLT stylesheet and the result)

Comment: I wanted to know how to transform xml file containing EcG raw data to xslt file.

Answer (score 0):

For graphics like bar chart, pie chart and so on you need java script help which would take your generated XML as input and pass some parameters to javascript which has the ability to produce graphics for you. You can also check FusionCharts on http://www.fusioncharts.com/products/suite/?gclid=CI71hJqsjbUCFVEX6wodPgYAeg